# Connect with jsch to a switch using ssh

Tags: jsch

this is my first time I ask a question here so i dont know how to properly post one, but i will do my best. I have the Jsch library in java but I dont know to connect to the switch using ssh2. How do you but the hostkey of the switch in the session?

my code has something like this...

```
private static final String user = "admin";
private static final String host = "172.16.13.3";
private static final Integer port = 22;
private static final String pass = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);



    session.setPassword(pass);
    session.connect();
```

but when its executed the program runs without any errors, but it never connects to the switch.... Thanks for your help!!

Comment: How do you know *it never connects to the switch* – does it hang in the `connect` method?

Comment: When you debug did you see "Connected=false" in Session Inspection? When you mention "it never connects to the switch" means it should throw an Exception.What ever Operation you are trying to do Using JSCH library session will be established if you give Correct parameters to Establish the session.Otherwise It will throw an Exception.